# Are Cosplay specific questions on or off topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

[Where can I find the same suit as the guy from the logo wears in Watch Dogs Legions?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/383152/where-can-i-find-the-same-suit-as-the-guy-from-the-logo-wears-in-watch-dogs-legi)

The question is asked pretty badly, and would still be recommendations, but would a question worded as 'What is that type of coat called' be inbounds?

Its on the line of 'What is this' but I do think like the game recommendation tag, if asked with a picture it could be on topic if it still is within videogames, like for cosplay.

In this case, It would still be useful I think because if someone is not from a northern country, they probably would not know that kind of coat is called a Trench coat

Comment: I'm leaving towards it being off-topic. If it were worded as such, it would be a request to identify something outside the realm of video games, which would start to become out of our scope. My memory is fuzzy, but I vaguely remember there being an identification request a while back to identify a gun that was found within a game, and it was eventually closed for the reason I gave

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it is, it's a where-can-I-find-this question, which in this form is considered off-topic on all Stack Exchange sites, as far as I know.

If the OP was looking for the name of the item of clothing it would also be off-topic here: that particular 'object' or its name have no bearing on the story or gameplay in the game (it would be different with e.g. the Portal Gun, but even then a question like 'What is this weapon called?' should be closed as being too silly).

We're not a search engine.

If the OP was looking for the name of the item of clothing in order to recreate it, or for specific questions focused on the creation of the outfit, [Arts & Crafts](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/) would be a good fit.

Comment: The only site I can think of that supports those kind of questions is Anime & Manga. Questions like asking "Where can I watch 'X' anime?" are acceptable as long as it's asking for legal resources

Comment: Well TIL there is a Arts and Crafts SE. Yeah the fit would be better there for cosplay. The basis for it being maybe on topic was mostly 'well if he cant ask it here, where could he ask it at the end of the day?'